# What are best steps to diagnose a bucking engine/

Tags: nissan, o2-sensor, fuel-injection, maf, obd-i

My 1992 Nissan with SR20DE (2.0 liter 143 HP o2 and MAF equipped OBD I engine, 16 valve, fuel injected), bucks. I own this car for ten years now and a lot has been replaced. Not always in attempt to solve the bucking at low rpm and small throttle and I solved a lot of issues already but this bucking that can be very annoying I still not made go away.

But before I start telling what has been done I would like to learn what are the steps to take to find the cause? Any trouble shooting tips will do!

Comment: Top mounting bushes on the engine, lower bushes on the box ...

Comment: That is not a bad answer because it is something that could be overlooked but my bucking is intermittent and really the engine. I also have prothane bushings. Nissan bushings are not known for being stiff or longevity.